# Pass variable ids_array array of integers in condition where and get error: column ids_array does not exist

Tags: postgresql

I declare variable `ids_array` as an array of integers.

Select all ids from a table and store them in this variable.
I want use this array in query in condition where `WHERE id = ANY(ARRAY[ids_array]::int[]))`

Get error:

> ```
> column "ids_array" does not exist  
> LINE 25:          WHERE id = ANY(ARRAY[ids_array]::int[])) AS ...
> ```

How correct pass array of ids?

```
do $$
DECLARE
   ids_array int[];
BEGIN
   SELECT ARRAY(SELECT id FROM tests) INTO ids_array;
END;
$$;

WITH tests_counts AS
    (SELECT DISTINCT ON (t.id)
            t.id
          , MAX(count_not_applicable) AS count_not_applicable
          , MAX(count_conclusion_true) AS count_conclusion_true
          , MAX(count_conclusion_false) AS count_conclusion_false
          , MAX(count_conclusion_blank) AS count_conclusion_blank         
     FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
                  id 
                , CASE WHEN not_applicable=true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS count_not_applicable
                , CASE WHEN not_applicable!=true AND conclusion=true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS count_conclusion_true
                , CASE WHEN not_applicable!=true AND conclusion=false THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS count_conclusion_false
                , CASE WHEN conclusion is null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS count_conclusion_blank
           FROM tests 
           WHERE id = ANY(ARRAY[ids_array]::int[])) AS t 
     GROUP BY t.id)
```

**Updated code** after @a_horse_with_no_name comment. Getting an error syntax **error at or near "END"
LINE 24: END;**

```
do $$

DECLARE 
    ids_array int[];
BEGIN
    SELECT ARRAY(SELECT id FROM control_tests) INTO ids_array;
       
    WITH control_tests_counts AS
     (SELECT DISTINCT ON (t.id) t.id
                               , MAX(count_not_applicable) AS count_not_applicable
                               , MAX(count_conclusion_true) AS count_conclusion_true
                               , MAX(count_conclusion_false) AS count_conclusion_false
                               , MAX(count_conclusion_blank) AS count_conclusion_blank

     FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id 
                           , CASE WHEN not_applicable=true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS count_not_applicable
                           , CASE WHEN not_applicable!=true AND conclusion=true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS count_conclusion_true
                           , CASE WHEN not_applicable!=true AND conclusion=false THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS count_conclusion_false
                           , CASE WHEN conclusion is null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS count_conclusion_blank
            FROM control_tests 
            WHERE id = ANY(ids_array)) AS t 
     GROUP BY t.id)        
   
END;
$$;

         
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS count 
    , COUNT (DISTINCT CASE WHEN count_not_applicable = 1 THEN id END) AS count_not_applicable
    , COUNT (DISTINCT CASE WHEN count_conclusion_true = 1 THEN id END) AS count_conclusion_true
    , COUNT (DISTINCT CASE WHEN count_conclusion_false = 1 THEN id END) AS count_conclusion_false
    , COUNT (DISTINCT CASE WHEN count_conclusion_blank = 1 THEN id END) AS count_conclusion_blank
FROM control_tests_counts;
```

Comment: The variable is not visible or usable outside of the PL/pgSQL block where it was declared. Additionally if a variable already is an array, then you don't need to create another array that contains the variable. `id = any(ids_array)` would be enough if that SELECT was part of the PL/pgSQL block where the variable is valid

Comment: Also, a CTE (`WITH` query) without main query is syntactical nonsense.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I updated code(cgeck please) and get syntax error at or near "END"
LINE 24: END;